# Error for copying from Jupyter to Zeppelin

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, apache-zeppelin

I currently use Jupyter notebook for my work and I want to move my work to Zeppelin notebook.
I just directly copy the content from Jupyter notebook and then paste to Zeppelin notebook, but syntax error occurs even I only copy one line with no indentation. Hence, it isn't an indentation problem.
I can't see any hidden character in several text editor.
How to correctly copy content from Jupyter notebook to Zeppelin notebook?

Comment: What is the error? have you add %pyspark as the first line before python code?

Comment: I added %python at the first line. I don't have any code using pyspark.
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Before cleaning record count"

There is no indentation.

Comment: Please add the whole error message or the screenshot in your question. It might be easier for others